# Terragrunt InvalidUserData.Malformed: Invalid BASE64 encoding of user data

Tags: terraform, terragrunt

I would like to use EOF in the user_data field of the autoscaling terraform module.

Example:

```
  user_data = <<-EOT
#!/bin/bash
cat <<'EOF' >> /etc/ecs/ecs.config
ECS_CLUSTER=${dependency.ecs_cluster.outputs.ecs_cluster_name}
ECS_LOGLEVEL=debug
ECS_ENABLE_TASK_IAM_ROLE=true
EOF
EOT
```

When I execute the code I get:

```
Error: creating EC2 Launch Template (autoscaling-group-ECS-20230725121233956900000001): InvalidUserData.Malformed: Invalid BASE64 encoding of user data.
```

I tried using the base64encode Function and still nothing works.

Please do you have an example on how to properly encode this as there is no example online neither the error shows what is wrong

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show us how you are using the module?